# RC circuit and tone

Tags: capacitor, audio, resistors

Can I generate a tone on an 8-ohm speaker using a 5VDC power source, resistor and capacitor? For example if I want to generate a 440 Hz tone, could I use resistor capacitor values such that RC = 1/440?

EDIT: power source

Comment: Conservation of energy is a factor you should consider - a tone outputted from a speaker is actual joules being emitted into the air every second. Have you considered where this energy is going to come from to power the speaker?

Comment: Apparently you added a 5VDC power source to your question, but you are still missing an amplifier of any kind (transistor, opamp, etc). In general, an oscillator needs both a frequency-determining element (the RC you mention can do this) and an amplifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything has some resonance, so certainly you might be able to wrangle a capacitor value that, with the inductance in the rest of the circuit (chiefly to be found in your speaker), you could hit a given frequency.

But the problem here is, you have nothing to excite that resonance into action. If you fully charged the capacitor and slapped it onto the speaker, you'd get nothing more than a damped oscillation. And by damped, we're not talking about anything you could experience. Odds are it would all be over in microseconds.

The usual way to 'generate a tone' is to use an amplifier (read: more parts) to sample that natural oscillation, take power from your DC supply and provide gain, and then feed the amplified signal back to the resonant section in order to sustain the oscillation.

Short answer: no.

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work.

1. When you combine the RC circuit, with the RL equivalent of the
   speaker, it may form a second order network that will oscillate, but
   it is not likely it will be at the frequency you want. Calculating that will involve a Laplace transform, and it will only oscillate if given stimulus.
2. Speakers transfer electric energy into kinetic energy. You have no energy source with just an RC circuit. You need some kind of semiconductor to form an oscillator. Using the speaker part of the oscillator is not a good idea. The RL values will be outside of a reasonable range for matching with the RC components. The oscillator should be built separately.
3. Once you have the oscillator functioning, you will need a power stage to drive the speaker.